# validation when setting html

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code that gets emails from the server side , shows them in a table, and when one of them is selected , I show that e-mail's body below the table.
The problem is that some emails contain bad html (e.g. opening tags with no matching closing tags) and this causes some nasty side effects in my site. (e.g. Failing to call server side with ajax call).

```
 createTable: function () {
        Loader.show();
        var html = '<span id="correspondenceTt">Correspondence History</span><table id="correspondence"><tr class="th"><th class="from">From</th><th class="to">To</th><th>Subject</th><th class="date">Date</th><th class="attachments">Attachments</th></tr>';

        for (var i = 0; i < mailViewer.mails.length; i++) {
            var mail = mailViewer.mails[i];

            html += '<tr id="' + i + '" class="odd">';
            html += mailViewer.reduceEmailList(this.fixMailAddress(mail.From), 30);
            html += mailViewer.reduceEmailList(this.fixMailAddress(mail.To), 30);
            html += mailViewer.reduceSection(mail.Subject, 45);
            html += mailViewer.reduceSection(d.toLocaleString(), 21);
            html += '<td class="att" id="' + mail.Id + '">';           
            html += '<div class="eml" id="' + i + 'html">' + '   ' + mail.Body + '</div></td></tr>';
        }
        html += '</table><div id="dipEmail" style="margin-top:' + Math.min(mailViewer.mails.length * 28 + 23, 248) + 'px;"><div id="mailContainer"></div></div>';
        mailViewer.setHtml(html);
```

Now my question is, how can I sanitize the html of the emails , or set it inside an element in such a way it will not effect my site's wrapping html?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject content into a container, and then invoke the normalize () method. This will return a valid content that can be removed to incorporate into your template. This is an example:

```
// Container element
var element = document.createElement('DIV');
var html = '<table><tr><td>ola</tr>';
element.innerHTML = html;
// Normalize
element.normalize();

console.log(element.innerHTML);
// return: <table><tbody><tr><td>ola</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: seem that `normalize` has no effect in your example

Comment: Thanks @vifito - unfortunately -  That indeed does not help